# Mongoose exclude fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

With mongoose is it possible to exclude fields when populating without select chaining?

I need to omit the author email and hashed password in this case:

```
.populate(ratings, { path: 'reviews.author', model: 'User' }, function(err, ratings) {
    ...    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following approach;

```
Model.find(...)
     .populate({
          path: 'reviews.author',
          model: 'User',
          select: '-email -password'
     })
     .exec(callback);
```

This will exclude the `email` and `password` fields.

Comment: it just exlcudes the first first field only. couldn't exclude more that one field. actually I'm having array of object ids

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`select`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Document_model.populate) attribute in your populate options:.

For example, if your user has `name` and `email` attributes, you could select them like this:

```
.populate(ratings, { path: 'reviews.author', model: 'User', select: 'name email' }, function(err, ratings) {
    ...    
});
```